# use server variables in build for development and production

Tags: next.js

I thought I could use ${process.env.apiservervariable} for my api calls. I added this into my env.development

NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_API_SERVER="http://localhost:8000"

which works for npm run dev. But when I build I get errors that I am using incomplete or relative paths. I've switched to using a next.config.js file and putting a var in there like so:

```
module.exports = {
env: {
    apiServer: "http://localhost:8000",
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE: "pk_test_hash"
  },
}
```

That works, but I have to hardcode it to change it based on the server I want to use. Is there a way to have a variable that gets read from dev when I am using npm run dev and a different one when I run npm run build? I develop locally and then push to github. I pull on the production server and want to be able to build on the server with a different variable for the live server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close with your first idea.

In Next.js you can have separate configuration files for development and production environments: create `.env.development` and `.env.production` in project root directory. `next dev` will load the development file and `next start` the production one. You should include your `API_SERVER` variable in both files with different values and expose them to the client side by preppending `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. Thus, you will be able to acces it in your frontend with `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_SERVER`.

```js
// .env.development
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_SERVER=http://localhost:3000
```

```js
// .env.production
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_SERVER=https://google.com
```

Comment: That’s how I had it setup, but build wasn’t reading the variables. It would only read them when I ran npm run dev

Comment: I discovered, I had left off the period before .env.production, but not .env.development, thus my problem. Thanks 83C10